# iOS 8.4 MPNowPlayingInfoCenter skip/prev disappeared

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8.4

I'm working on a music playing app and in previous iOS versions the media player would show the play/pause as well as the skip and prev buttons.  Now, with the 8.4 update, all that is shown is the play/pause.  I'm updating the MPNowPlayingInfoCenter in the usual way:

```
NSDictionary* nowPlayingInfo = @{
    MPMediaItemPropertyTitle:[self.currentSong title],
    MPMediaItemPropertyArtist:[self.currentSong artist],
    MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:(double) self.duration],
    MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime: [NSNumber numberWithDouble:(double)self.currentPlaybackTime],
    MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate: self.isPlaying ? @1.0 : @0.0,
    MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork: mediaPlayerArtwork,
    MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackQueueIndex: [NSNumber numberWithInteger:playQueue.queuePosition],
    MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackQueueCount: [NSNumber numberWithInteger:playQueue.queueIDs.count] };
[[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter] setNowPlayingInfo:nowPlayingInfo];
```

But the result is...
[image]

and
[image]

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to get the next and prev buttons back you need to add:

```
[[MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter].nextTrackCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(remoteNextPrevTrackCommandReceived:)];
[[MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter].previousTrackCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(remoteNextPrevTrackCommandReceived:)];
```

I added this in AppDelegate's

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {`

If you're already receiving remote events the action method can be empty:

`-(void) remoteNextPrevTrackCommandReceived:(id)event {}`